# PHP Parsing Multidimensional JSON Array

Tags: php, parsing, json

I'm using the Angel list api to pull this data and trying to parse it via this code (pull through attempted parse)

The Parsing code isn't working properly and will not retrieve the value for [id] for some reason. I have been looking up json depth and think that may be the problem and have tried many different approaches but nothing seems to be working. Can someone assist in helping to pull individual values from the nested arrays?

```
$ch = curl_init($array_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = json_decode($data);
print $response->{'name'};
echo "\n";
```

Example Output

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 79840
        [pic] => https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos.angel.co/startups/i/79840-e351f55eea90356818e586ca3e547981-thumb_jpg.jpg?buster=1333248008
        [url] => https://angel.co/joinastartup-org
        [name] => JoinAStartup.org
        [type] => Startup
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 121425
        [pic] => https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos.angel.co/startups/i/121425-7cea796d5afc33877d68c633963ec8e9-thumb_jpg.jpg?buster=1353964843
        [url] => https://angel.co/jointly
        [name] => Jointly
        [type] => Startup
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 76554
        [pic] => https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos.angel.co/startups/i/76554-d227b51eac3509eeba4cced14186b782-thumb_jpg.jpg?buster=1347923043
        [url] => https://angel.co/supportlocal
        [name] => SupportLocal
        [type] => Startup
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 30334
        [pic] => https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos.angel.co/startups/i/30334-219f36ea273ef199c2aaf7b034554b90-thumb_jpg.jpg?buster=1326922125
        [url] => https://angel.co/jointli
        [name] => Jointli
        [type] => Startup
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 14278
        [pic] => https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos.angel.co/startups/i/14278-8b9059bb1fa7fab5813dfbade19056eb-thumb_jpg.jpg?buster=1315736993
        [url] => https://angel.co/joint
        [name] => joint
        [type] => Startup
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 22687
        [pic] => https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos.angel.co/startups/i/22687-94e1104706736e7636d23ff055819b8c-thumb_jpg.jpg?buster=1337954356
        [url] => https://angel.co/join-our-talents
        [name] => Join Our Talents
        [type] => Startup
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [id] => 45059
        [pic] => 
        [url] => https://angel.co/joint-research-centre
        [name] => Joint Research Centre
        [type] => Startup
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [id] => 119433
        [pic] => https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos.angel.co/startups/i/119433-585159079dc0e8b31156e772d53914de-thumb_jpg.jpg?buster=1346721187
        [url] => https://angel.co/joinspeaker-1
        [name] => JoinSpeaker
        [type] => Startup
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [id] => 40214
        [pic] => 
        [url] => https://angel.co/advanced-joining-technology
        [name] => Advanced Joining Technology
        [type] => Startup
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [id] => 35338
        [pic] => https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos.angel.co/startups/i/35338-52ca618ccef71f1a67b21e2e838a4674-thumb_jpg.jpg?buster=1326845104
        [url] => https://angel.co/joingo
        [name] => Joingo
        [type] => Startup
    )

)
```

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question is why isn't the print statement working? First, you have `<br>` at end of every line, that's not valid PHP syntax and I hope that's not in your actual code.

Second, regarding the print statement... response is an array, so you access it using:

```
$response[0]['name']
```

Replace `0` with the index of the element you want to access. You can even use a loop to iterate over the results and get all the names

```
$len = count($response);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
    print $response[$i]['name'];
}
```

You can also use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

Comment: the <br> were just to make the formatting work on SO, my paste was acting strange. Attempting to implement now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the array using something like `foreach`, and example would be

Change:

```
print $response->{'name'};
```

To:

```
foreach ($response as $r) {
    echo $r['name'];
}
```